# How to passing data from Javascript to lua

Tags: javascript, lua

How to passing data from javascript to lua ?

```
for(var i = 1; i<= totalsd; i++){
   if( eval('q' + i) == null || eval('q' + i) == ''){
    var number = i
    alert(number)
    $.post('http://ns_45/unfinishtk',JSON.stringify({number}));
    return false;
    }
}
```

Lua

```
RegisterNUICallback('unfinishtk', function(number)
   print(number)
end)
```

When i try to do alert , it's shown the correct value , but when i try to pass it to lua , it's wont detect the value

Comment: Where is your lua code that reads the json and decodes it?

Comment: edited for the lua code

Comment: Where are you decoding the json in your lua code?  Lua can't work with json natively.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

```
for(var i = 1; i<= totalsd; i++){
   if( eval('q' + i) == null || eval('q' + i) == ''){
    var number = i
    $.post('http://ns_45/unfinishtk',JSON.stringify({number:number}));
    return false;
    }
}
```

Lua

```
RegisterNUICallback('unfinishtk', function(data,cb)
   print(data.number)
end)
```